# SQL DROP TABLE FUNCTION

Tags: sql

Hello i've created a table if in a VM provided by my university and inserted the following:

```
create table first_table (record_id int primary key,
first_name varchar(20) not null,
last_name varchar(20) not null);
```

However, instead of the first_name and last_name I actually inserted my name and am looking to drop the table to recreate it.

"    I typed in `DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] first_table`    "

and then it simply doesn't do anything. Any idea why.

Comment: Can you provide some information that could help us debug, such as which database server you're using, and what client you're using to issue commands to it?  Also, did you remember to put a trailing semicolon on it?

Comment: Assuming that's just how you typed it, take out the brackets that are around the `[IF EXISTS]` clause of the `DROP` statement.

Comment: Simply do `DROP TABLE first_table;`

Comment: Im using PuTTY connecting to it via a VM provided by my University, I logged in using my password and then typed in: "psql" to connect to my psql and then wrote create table second_table (record_id int primary key,
first_name varchar(20) not null,
last_name varchar(20) not null);

Comment: Context - However instead of first_name i typed my actual name which is why im trying to get rid of the table

Answer (score 1):

In the Postgresql documentation, when you see something inside square brackets such as `[IF EXISTS]` it means that "IF EXISTS" is optional. You shouldn't type the square brackets if you put that in.

In this case, though, you know that the table exists so just leave the "IF EXISTS" part off:

```
drop table first_table;
```

Given that the problem is that you typed your first and last names instead of the desired column name (`first_name` and `last_name`) you can simply rename the columns using

```
alter table first_table
  rename leo as first_name

alter table first_table
  rename whatever_your_last_name_is as last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`DROP TABLE first_table;`

Comment: That's SQL Server specific syntax. Sybase might take it, too, I suppose, but that won't fly if this is MySQL or what have you, and the OP hasn't specified.

Comment: i enter the command psql not MYSQL  and I receive this error :up2041346=# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [first_table];
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [first_table];

Answer (score 0):

In PSQL you should be able to do so using the command
`DROP TABLE first_table;`